# What set of crops provide a complete diet?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, constraints, mixed-integer-programming

I'm trying to find what combination and quantity of crops I should grow to provide a complete diet. Basically, I have a set of n possible crops that I can grow, and I have m nutritional requirements. So, I need to solve an underdetermined m x n matrix to find the quantities needed of each crop. It seems simple at first, but there are a couple other requirements:

First, I'd like to minimize the number of things I have to grow. Obviously growing every possible crop in sufficient quantity will provide a complete diet, but that's obviously not feasible. From what I've researched, solving the system while minimizing the $l_0$ norm will minimize the number of crops.

Secondly, for many dietary requirements, there is a maximum allowable amount. So, in addition to the minimum requirements, the solution should also be subject to maximum inequality constraints. For example, if I consumed only Spirulina, I could meet many of the minimum nutritional requirements, but I would consume too much Copper, Magnesium, etc.

Seriously, though, I'm just trying to grow a garden here. The only way I know to compute all this is with NumPy and friends, and it seems like a lot of work for what I'd think was a common kind of problem. Is there an easier/better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your description suggests a problem that can be formulated as a combination of linear inequalities, and thus solved by standard methods of Linear Programming.  However your write up contains no specific information about what variables are involved (which crops, etc.) nor what constraints need to be imposed.  Of course you could set up a spreadsheet which tabulates all the crop and nutrient information and play around until you get a satisfactory solution.

Comment: What is arguably the very first optimization problem,which gave rise to the whole topic of maximizing or minimizing a linear function subject to linear costraints, by the simplex method, was George J. Stigler's paper "The cost of subsistence" that appeared in 1945 in the Journal of Farm Economics and was about exactly your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @P.Lawrence mentioned in a comment, your problem is an extension of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler_diet, which is a linear programming problem.  In your extension, instead of minimizing cost, you want to minimize the number of crops.  For each crop $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, let nonnegative decision variable $x_j$ indicate the amount of crop $j$ used, and let binary decision variable $y_j$ indicate whether crop $j$ is grown.  Let $M_j$ be a constant upper bound on $x_j$.  The (mixed integer linear programming) problem is to minimize the $\ell_0$ norm $\sum_{j=1}^n y_j$ subject to linear "big-M" constraints
$$x_j \le M_j y_j \quad \text{for all $j$} \tag1\label1$$
and Stigler's original linear constraints on $x$.
Constraint \eqref{1} enforces the logical proposition $x_j > 0 \implies y_j = 1$.

Comment: If my answer satisfies you, please mark it as accepted.